# Kibana 4 DateTime Displaying Local Values

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm storing data in ElasticSearch that looks something like:
"_source": {
               "realtimestamp": "2014-12-05",
               …
            },

And I have users in different time zones creating Kibana 4 Charts to view the data.
The problem is that we would like for the Kibana 4 Charts to show the time values in UTC Time Zone and NOT in the user's local time zone.

The image shows how the date value is being rendered now (NOT in UTC):[image: the image below shows how the value is currently being rendered]

Any idea how I can get Kibana 4 to display date values in UTC to the user?
THANKS! - Matt

Answer (score 4):

There is still stuff missing in K4B3 ("*beta* 3").  I don't see much timezone support.  See this ticket:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1600

Comment: Thanks man! Very helpful to at least know they are tracking it

Answer (score 0):

What about you to do that in you logstash's filter

```
filter{   
...
   date{
      match => ["dateHour", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"]
      timezone => "America/Sao_Paulo"
   }
}
```

Doing that Logstash will parse `dateHour` item and send to Elasticsearch using UTC timezone. Therefore you will be able to watch those data in Kibana.